# Mongodb natural sorting order for boolean field

Tags: mongodb

What is the natural order for a boolean field in MongoDB?

In other words, if I execute a query with a `{ $sort : { booleanField : 1 } }`, and I have the following documents field values:

```
Document A: booleanField=true
Document B: booleanField=false
Document C: booleanField=null/non-existent
```

In what order will they be retrieved?

Comment: Have you checked out [this official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#std-label-bson-types-comparison-order)?

Comment: why don't you just try it out, and share the result as an answer yourself?

Comment: Yes @ray, it only indicates `MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest`, but doesn't give any details on what is "low" or "high" in term of boolean values.

Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: The documentation does not state how each boolean value compares to other boolean values (true/false). It just says how it compares to other types, null would come first.

Comment: And will do @Simulant , but I have posted the question in advance as I am working on the solution, to give the chance to answer this to other contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Validated by example. The natural order should be:

```
Document C: booleanField=null/non-existent
Document B: booleanField=false
Document A: booleanField=true
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/2PI7WO7LGBF

Comment: Null and non-existent are considered equivalent for sorting, so the order of C1 and C2 will be determined by the order they were inserted, and may not be the same for subsequent queries in a sharded cluster.  See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rlMLNF--tG6